# Html - Making the form responsive when changing size of page

Tags: html, css, django

In my Django project, I am to make my site fully responsive. So far, I do this by adding this piece of code for my background:

CSS:

```
 div {
            background-image: url("{% static 'spotifywallpaper.jpg' %}");
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
 }
```

I then have a form. I generate this form using Django. Here is my form code in html:

```
{% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }}
                    <br>

                {% endfor %}
```

CSS:

```
.signupform {
                position: absolute;
                background-size: cover;
                left: 600px;
                top:150px;
            }
```

When I resize my page, the form stays static and does not move. What I want is when I shorten my page down in resolution, I want to make the form cover the page so it can then be actually seen by the user. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: media queries is the solution

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Hello I am aware of media queries. What I want to know is how can I actually get the form to move when page gets to a certain size. What will the code look like is what I am interested in

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

You can adjust the left and top to anything you like.

```css
.form-container {
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;
left: 200px;
top:150px;
width: 300px;
}
input {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .form-container {
    left: 0;
    top:100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
<input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="phone"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="address"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have pasted this code into my project and I realised this is not what I want. This is because when I resize my page, the form stays in the exact same position. I want to move the form when the resolution shrinks so the user can actually see the form.

Comment: Please check my original post to see the method I use to make my image responsive, and try find a solution to use that method for the form.

Comment: NP, Glad to be a help :)